Citrox and oral microbiome
X-Pur's Opti-Rinse has a good reputation among dental hygienists as an anti-gingivitis due to its use of Citrox.  I wonder how the oral microbiome is impacted.  This page describes it as much gentler and natural compared to alcohol mouthwashes.  However, I consider the latter to be a very low bar.
I am not a life scientist but I've searched for research on the impact of Citrox on the oral microbiome.  I haven't found anything.  Has there been any studies of this?
What motivates this question is the awareness of the fact that some medical treatments (e.g., for H-Pylori) eradicate the bad elements of the gut microbiome, but also significantly impact the rest of the microbiome (even the good elements).  I wonder whether there have been studies into whether oral treatments may also impact good elements of the oral microbiome, i.e., not just how well it targets the bad elements.

What did you search for? Just plugging the word citrox into google produces lots of useful hits. For example https://www.nature.com/articles/sj.bdj.2010.1224. Check the references for more. And google scholar produces even more useful hits.

@Carey Gregory: I did a general web search and Google Scholar.  While there is much online about combatting bad elements, I found none about the microbiome in general, e.g., maybe razing the desirable elements.  If you came across some, I'd appreciate it if you would post a link or two.

If I put just oral microbiome (with no hyphen) into google scholar I get 600K+ hits and many of them clearly address the subject in both general and specific ways. So I don't think I understand what you're looking for and why what's out there doesn't address your underlying question.

I just realized that one of two links in my last comment weren't right.  They both contain the phrase "citrox oral-microbiom" (without quotes).  The dash used to be the Google indicator for word proximity, though these days, it seems to serve a much looser constraint.  My results from removing the dash aren't much different.  Lots of links about antibacterial and antimicrobial properties, but none about whether it doesn't harm the good bacteria.

The reason I'm searching is because some gut treatments for other conditions wipe out gut microbiome. I wondered whether the same caution has been extended for oral treatments.  If you actually find studies on whether good parts of the microbiome are preserved, I would appreciate it if you posted just a few recent ones. Thanks.  And specifically about Citrox.

I don't know of any and it's not something I'm particularly interested in investigating. I would recommend that  you edit your question to make it more clear that you're looking for information showing specifically that it does or does not harm helpful bacteria. All you've asked is a generic "how does it affect" the oral microbiome, and there are tons of studies addressing that.

Will do.  Thanks.
